# Proof of $\dim({\rm Ker}(g\circ f)) \leq \dim({\rm Ker}(f)) + \dim({\rm Ker}(g))$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

This is an exercise that appeared in an Algebra II final exam from some years ago I found while studying a few days ago:

> Let $U, V, W$ be finite-dimensional K-Vector spaces and $f:U \rightarrow V$, $g:V \rightarrow W$ linear transformations. Prove that:
>
> $$\dim({\rm Ker}(g\circ f)) \le \dim({\rm Ker}(f)) + \dim({\rm Ker}(g)) $$
>
> HINT: Consider the restriction of $f$ to the space ${\rm Ker}(g\circ f)$

So far I only got that

$$\dim({\rm Ker}(g\circ f))=\dim({\rm Im}(f\restriction_{{\rm Ker}(g\circ f)}))$$

using the hint given, but I've been thinking for a while and I don't know how to link that to ${\rm Ker}(f)$ and ${\rm Ker}(g)$. I thought it might be related to the dimension of the direct sum.

I also found an answered question for this same exact proof but it has a different approach, so I was wondering if someone could give me some guidance for the proof using the hint given.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my answer to an equivalent problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4642476/302781).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f’ \colon \ker(g \circ f) \to V$ is the restriction of $f$ to $\ker(g \circ f)$, then
$$
\ker(f’) = \ker(g \circ f) \cap \ker(f) = \ker(f) \\ \& \quad \text{im}(f’) = f(\ker(g \circ f)) \subseteq \ker(g).
$$
What does the rank-nullity theorem say when applied to $f'$?

Comment: I can see that $dim(ker(g\circ f))\le dim(ker(g))$ and just that would make it so that we get the inequality $dim(ker(g\circ f))\le dim(ker(f))+dim(ker(g))$ through the rank-nullity theorem. However, why is it $ker(f')=ker(g\circ f)\cap ker(f)=ker(f)$ and not $ker(f')=ker(g\circ f)\cap ker(f)\subseteq ker(f)$?

Comment: @Aerin $\ker(f’) = \ker(g \circ f) \cap \ker(f)$ is by definition, and $\ker(g \circ f) \cap \ker(f) = \ker(f)$ is because $\ker(f) \subseteq \ker(g \circ f)$. But, as you points, $\ker(g \circ f) \cap \ker(f) \subseteq \ker(f)$ is enough to prove the desired inequality.